# Not able to generate entities with EF6 and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

[image: Visual studio 2013 entity generation tool]

Trying to generate the entities with VS2013 using MYSQL connector/net 6.8.3.0 but it shows me the above error. Following are the screenshots of installed applications list and Nuget package manager.

[image: Control Panel installed applications]

[image: Nuget Package manager]

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MYSQL EF6 is having a new dll "MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll". Refer this dll in your assembly, rebuild the application and try again to generate the entities.